# can't filter a thing with 2 inner join in 2 different r tabels

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following code, so far

```
temp <- dplyr::intersect(
Filme %>%
  inner_join(Distributie)%>%
  left_join(Cineasti,by = ('codactor' = 'codcineast'),
            filter (country == 'Romania'))%>%
select(moviename),
Filme %>%
  inner_join(Distributie)%>%
  left_join(Cineasti,by = ('codactor' = 'codcineast'),
            filter (country == 'Franta')%>%
  select(moviename)
```

And I'll like to know how to make it work. All I need is to check 2 tabels, in the first one I need it to make the link on < cod film > which is joining anyway, and on the other one to check if one of the actors is from a specific country but nothing seems to work..

Comment: You need to pipe the output of `left_join` to `filter` it is not a function argument.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack! It's a little difficult to tell what you're trying to do, but first issue I see is you're trying to use `filter` inside of `left_join`. The proper way to filter data inside the join is like so:

```
temp <- dplyr::intersect(
    Filme %>%
      inner_join(Distributie)%>%
      left_join(Cineasti %>%
         filter(country == 'Romania'), by = ('codactor' = 'codcineast')) %>%
      select(moviename),
    Filme %>%
      inner_join(Distributie)%>%
      left_join(Cineasti %>%
         filter(country == 'Franta'), by = ('codactor' = 'codcineast')) %>%
      select(moviename)
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the help so far
I'll try to make it more clear.
I have to get the movies in which there plays at least one person born in USA and one person born in France
So I have to get the movie name from table filme. In table Cineasti are the location of birth for each person, and on Distributie I have the link from cineasti to filme

 (https://imgur.com/a/CcBU677)

Comment: See edited answer above. Let me know if that solved your issue.